# How to resize and center an image and text on <li> grid?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, centering

I have this code:

```
<div>
 <ul class="g">
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev1.jpg" /></a><p>Only God Forgives</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev2.jpg" /></a><p>Place To be</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev3.jpg" /></a><p>Smokey Taboo</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev4.jpg" /></a><p>Pagan Poetry</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev1.jpg" /></a><p>Into The Wild</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev2.jpg" /></a><p>Mad G Wine</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev3.jpg" /></a><p>Milk And Beach</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev4.jpg" /></a><p>Song To The Siren</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev1.jpg" /></a><p>Where The Wild Things Are</p></li>
  <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev2.jpg" /></a><p>At Night in Dreams</p></li>
</div>


.g {
  margin: 2%;
}
.g li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.g img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; }
```

**I want to resize the images inside the li, which are yellow boxes. I want the images to be almost the size of the yellow box but stay centered and the text centered too, in one line only.**

I thought that would be easy by simply changing the size of the images like this

```
.g img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
```

}

but the images get out of place, not centered and the text disappears in some of the boxes.

**I have tried so many different things that I have no idea what else I can do.**

PS. This is also supposed to be responsive. But all I have managed to do is to make the yellow squares change position when the browser shrinks or enlarges (good enough!). But I would also like that the yellow squares (along with the images inside) would change their size just a little bit. But every code I tried made it look weird and the yellow boxes would jump spaces, creating gaps between each other were they weren't supposed to. (This is not a priority, just something I'd like to add if possible)

I'm new to html and css so this is kinda hard for me! I'd really appreciate some help.

**I tried to upload photos to show the problem but it appears I need "10 reputation" and so I couldn't :( If anyone is willing to help me and need to see pictures, I can send them or something. Thank you!**

Comment: try editing you post and add images now. Also ... try preparing a jsfiddle so we can better understand your needs and help you solve them.

Comment: Can you show us your best code so far? (Like is JSFiddle, JSBin or something like this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your wishes correctly, I think this is what you want:

```js
window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;

//GET PAGE WIDTH---------------------------------
function getPageWidth() {
  if (typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') { //non-IE
    return window.innerWidth;
  } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) { //IE6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) { //IE4 compatible
    return document.body.clientWidth;
  }
}

//RESIZE-----------------------------------------
function resize() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize = 10 * (getPageWidth()/1366) +'pt'; //1366 is your base-width, change it to the width of your development-monitor
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.g {
  margin: 2%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.g li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5%;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.g img {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 5%; /*must be half of '100% - width'*/
  background: blue; /*FOR TESTING ONLY*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="g">
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev1.jpg" /></a><p>Only God Forgives</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev2.jpg" /></a><p>Place To be</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev3.jpg" /></a><p>Smokey Taboo</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev4.jpg" /></a><p>Pagan Poetry</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev1.jpg" /></a><p>Into The Wild</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev2.jpg" /></a><p>Mad G Wine</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev3.jpg" /></a><p>Milk And Beach</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev4.jpg" /></a><p>Song To The Siren</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev1.jpg" /></a><p>Where The Wild Things Are</p></li>
    <li><a href="proj1.html"><img src="img/prev2.jpg" /></a><p>At Night in Dreams</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0fbdgfcq/1/**

---

- I've added `list-style-type:none;` to the `.g` rules, that removes those black dots. (I assumed that's what you would want.)
- I made the `li`s responsive by setting `width:15%;` (play around with the percentage).
- I centered the images by setting `width:90%;` (and height) and `margin:5%;`.
- To make the text-size (font-size) responsive, I had to use JavaScript. It works like this:

  - In CSS, I set the font-size for the entire body to 10pt: `body{font-size: 10pt;}`. This is the base-size.
  - Next, I give `.g li` a relative font-size: `font-size: 1em;`. `1em` means *1x the size of its first ancestor with absolute font-size* (so, the body's 10pt). **If you want a bigger start-font-size for the text, DO NOT change the body's font-size, BUT change the `.g li`'s font-size instead (`1.2em` for `12pt` for instance)!**
  - Finally, I call the function `resize()` on `window.onload` and `window.onresize`. In that function, I change the body's font-size with this line:

    `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize = 10 * (getPageWidth()/1366) +'pt';`

    '1366' is your base-width, change it to the width of your development-monitor.
  - The `getPageWidth()` function is just for cross-browser functionality. If you're only developing for new browsers with HTML5, I think `window.innerWidth` should suffice.

(I gave the images a blue background for testing purposes only, that can be removed.)

Answer (score 1):

try `max-width: 100%;` on your image instead of `width: 300px;` to keep your images contained inside the li.

To center your images:

`position: relative;` on your li's

and `position: absolute` on your images and

set your image `position` with `top, right, bottom, left`.

These are just quick options, if you could add a jsfiddle of you problem you will likley get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might make sense to set the size of the boxes to something fixed and then add a border around it rather than worry about sizing the images just right to center them.  The border can be 'fake' filler.  Start with the box size and border first THEN adjust the image.

Something like:

```
.g img {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: somevalue-px;
  left: somevalue-px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```